# Security test fails on freemember:update_profile form

Tags: freemember, security, xss

**EDIT**

This question is related to compliance to a specific security test, the problem has nothing to do with Freemember extension. 
For the record : The solution found to pass the test was to simply str_replace the posted data to remove anything between < > before it's sent to the database.

---

Security test flags : **Cross-Site Scripting: Persistent** on freemember:update_profile form

The test machine manages to insert javascript code in the form fields

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that freemember is either pulling in values from the form using the unclean `$_POST` array or using `ee()->input->post('var_name');` (note the lack of second security parameter which should be `true`). I suspect the former as using the EE function (on latest 2.10.1) I *beleive* still strips dangerous script tags regardless of the XSS_Clean parameter.

Because of the lack of detail here I can only surmise, however I would take a look through the modules code, identify where it gets the posted values and change the method of retrieval to

```
ee()->input->post('var_name', true);
```

This should then parse and clean the posts.

Another alternative is that you've changede the XSS Cleaning setting (in `Admin > Security`) to no or off. Please review this setting.

If I where you I'd submit this as a bug on freemember if your security settings are correct but it's still defeating them, the module is by DevDemon so you can [submit an issue here](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/issues?state=open)

Lastly, you *have* set an encryption key on freemember, right?? [Docs](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember)

Comment: I see nothing suspicious in freemember, it uses the secure parameter. The secure forms parameter in Admin > Security has been removed and forms are now secure by default. Yes, I use an encryption key. I've submitted an issue on devdemon's GitHub.

Comment: HI laurent, ok so much for the 'usual suspects' then! What type of field is it that is letting script through? Also I don't suppose you can share the attack vector used that exposed the weakness? I'm wondering if there's a potentual issue within a 3rd party fieldtype...

Comment: Alas, I have no 'special fieldtype', the script is passed through a custom field _firstname_ it is a simple input field...

Comment: I know this is old, but https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/issues/85 suggests a fix for this

Comment: The bugfix quoted by WOUNDEDStevenJones looks quite correct to me! Indeed this is where I was leading to when I said to scan the source and look for where it handles the inputs. The form on the bugfix is essentually the same deal with up to date EE3 style code (perhaps EE2.2+ even as its using the ee() super), instead of setting XXS Clean on the call to post(), call it explicitly, where it didnt before.... Thanks for the link :)